TV show that has similar cartoons
I recently saw this commercial. 
Now, I remember as a kid(early to mid 80's), watching a TV show that had a cartoon character exactly like that. Just the whole art style of this commercial reminded me of this. But I can't for the life of me remember the name of the show! I'm about 70% sure that it wasn't a full cartoon show, but a life action show that had these cartoon moments.  
Anyone know or recognize this?  

Kind of reminds me of The Pink Panther

Pink panther was a full blown cartoon though, wasn't it?

Ah, didn't see the last part of the question.

I guess it pays to read more.  In the comments, the name of the cartoon is listed.  It's La Linea.  Though the wikipedia link shows what TV shows it was on in America, I'm still not sure that either of those was it, as I didn't have Nickelodeon until mid-90s.  And Great Space Coaster doesn't even ring a bell.  But, it's entirely possible that was the show.
